# Load the view when app starts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, view

I want to create a app with only one view(TestViewController.h TestViewController.m). (no Tabbar, no Navigation Bar) Don't know why after i launch the app, the screen is totally black. It seems that the app did not load the view successfully? Since if the view is loaded, the screen should be white. Am I right or not?

Here's AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class TestViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    TestViewController *testrViewController;   
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TestViewController *testViewController;

@end
```

Here's AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = window;
@synthesize testViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window addSubview:testViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: check Mainwindow.xib, do you have `TestViewController` in it?

Comment: @iShrey, I guess, there are no xib files..

Comment: I want to create it programmically without IB, so I did not creat xib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are creating it programmatically, then you should also instantiate `window`

```
UIWindow *aWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window = aWindow;
[aWindow release];
```

then your ViewController

```
testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
```

and then make it visible

```
[self.window addSubview:testViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you're not instatiating the class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 // add this line
 testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
 [.....]
 }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

did you create .xib for testViewController. If not then you have to add a subview  over your testViewController. and then try. I hope it will work.

```
UIView *testView=[[UIView alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

[testViewController addsubview:testView];
[self.window addSubview:testViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```